# Created Gem. But Class / Gem is not available after install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I just created this GEM [AX-Track API Wrapper](https://github.com/fydelio/ax-track-ruby-client) (following the most recent tutorials from GoRails), but after installing it into a new rails project, I don't have the functionality available. Somehow the main class is not loaded!

What did I do

- Create a new rails project
- add to gemfile: `gem 'ax-track-ruby-client'`
- run `bundle install`
- spin up console and run `AxTrack::Client`

The error I get

```
NameError (uninitialized constant AxTrack)
```

What do I need to change in this gem to make the functionality available.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your gem is `ax-track-ruby-client` (seen from [gemspec file](https://github.com/fydelio/ax-track-ruby-client/blob/79f81a6bcbb9c00ade19353473a6280b0557ef55/ax_track.gemspec#L8)). You should use that when installing the gem (or update the name listed in the gemspec file).

Comment: That's what I did. sorry, sorry for not being precise enough. I updated the question.

Comment: I believe you will also need to run `require 'ax-track'` (that is the latest name I saw in the gem's repo) in the rails console before having access to the classes in that gem.

And here is a guide for naming conventions of gems, https://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/.